# Build error: missingLinuxMain

Tags: swift, linux

I have a bug when I try to build a swift package on linux :

```
> swift build -v
lsb_release -r
which clang
/opt/swift/usr/bin/swiftc --driver-mode=swift -L /opt/swift/usr/lib/swift/pm/4 -lPackageDescription -swift-version 4 -I /opt/swift/usr/lib/swift/pm/4 -sdk / /home/me/SwiftProject/Package.swift -fileno 5
/opt/swift/usr/bin/swiftc --driver-mode=swift -L /opt/swift/usr/lib/swift/pm/3 -lPackageDescription -swift-version 3 -I /opt/swift/usr/lib/swift/pm/3 -sdk / /home/me/SwiftProject/.build/checkouts/siesta-3156441904511450749/Package.swift -fileno 5
/opt/swift/usr/bin/swiftc --driver-mode=swift -L /opt/swift/usr/lib/swift/pm/3 -lPackageDescription -swift-version 3 -I /opt/swift/usr/lib/swift/pm/3 -sdk / /home/me/SwiftProject/.build/checkouts/SwiftyJSON-6376406316629445150/Package.swift -fileno 5
error: missingLinuxMain
```

I have no error when I run the last command:

```
/opt/swift/usr/bin/swiftc --driver-mode=swift -L /opt/swift/usr/lib/swift/pm/3 -lPackageDescription -swift-version 3 -I /opt/swift/usr/lib/swift/pm/3 -sdk / /home/me/SwiftProject/.build/checkouts/SwiftyJSON-6376406316629445150/Package.swift -fileno 5
```

I have a file LinuxMain.swift in the Test directory:

```
Tests
├── ProjectTests
│   ├── SomeTests.swift
└── LinuxMain.swift
```

LinuxMain.swift:

```
import XCTest
@testable import ProjectTests

XCTMain([
    testCase(SomeTests.allTests),
])
```

I use swift 4.0 on ubuntu 17.04

Comment: Which package are you building? Is it one you created yourself or something you cloned from GitHub?

Comment: One I created myself

Answer (score 16, accepted):

SwiftPM uses a file named `LinuxMain.swift` (located in the root directory of your test targets, usually `Tests/LinuxMain.swift`) to find the unit tests on Linux. (On Apple platforms it uses the Objective-C runtime for this, but that's not available on Linux.)

It looks like your build fails because SwiftPM can't find the file.

If you haven't got a `LinuxMain.swift` file, you should create one. The easiest way to see how it should be formatted is probably to run `swift package init` in an empty directory and check out the expected directory and file structure.

The file should look something like this, but adapted for your package (I copied this one from [here](https://github.com/JohnSundell/Marathon/blob/master/Tests/LinuxMain.swift)):

```
import XCTest
@testable import MarathonTests

XCTMain([
     testCase(MarathonTests.allTests)
])
```

Each of your `XCTestCase` subclasses also needs an `allTests` property. Again, the default directory structure should give you an idea how it should look.

You might also find [this article I wrote a few months ago](https://oleb.net/blog/2017/03/keeping-xctest-in-sync/) interesting.

Comment: I have this file

Comment: Today you can also run `swift test --generate-linuxmain` to create & update the file.